# How do I keep my while loop from stopping?

Tags: java, swing, loops, while-loop

I have been working on a small RPG game recently. Currently, I have run up against a problem where the while loop which manages which actor object can act stops whenever I select Go! from the GUI. I have the while loop in my main method file, RPGv6, and the GUI in another file, BattleUI. I am supposed to select an action (such as "Attack") from the row of buttons, then click on the enemy I want to attack. This supplies the type of action and the target to an executeSkills methods, and the while loop supplies the currentActor. However, whenever I press the Go! button and execute this method, the while loop stops. When I have pressed the button, that player's turnTaken is supposed to be set to true and the while loop is supposed to set the currentActor to 1 (for the next actor).

In a previous version, I managed to have a while loop and a GUI interacting in much this way, so I know it can be done- I just do not know how to resolve this current problem.

```
    public class RPGv6 
{
public static actor[] player = new actor[3];
public static actor[] enemy  = new actor[3];
public static String selectionName = "";
public static boolean actionDetermined = false;
public static boolean targetDetermined = false;
public static boolean permission       = false;
public static int currentActor = 0;
public static Abilities actionSkills;

boolean placeholder = true;

public static void main(String[] args)
{


    createActors();
    System.out.println("actors created");
    BattleUI.createAndShowGui(player, enemy);
    System.out.println("gui created");

    boolean //Using these booleans as loop conditions does not work; not sure why; works in the if statements just below
    playerWin       = (enemy[0].dead == true && (enemy[1].dead == true) && (enemy[2].dead == true)),
    enemyWin        = (player[0].dead == true && (player[1].dead == true) && (player[2].dead == true));

    while(!playerWin && !enemyWin)
    {
        if(enemy[1].dead == true && (enemy[2].dead == true) && (enemy[3].dead == true))
            break;
        if(player[1].dead == true && (player[2].dead == true) && (player[3].dead == true))
            break;

        // player turn
        if(!player[0].turnTaken)
        {
            currentActor = 0;
                                    //System.out.println("loop executing");
        }
        if((!player[1].turnTaken) && (player[1].turnTaken))
        {
            currentActor = 1;
        }
        if((!player[2].turnTaken) && (player[2].turnTaken) && (player[1].turnTaken))
        {   
            currentActor = 2;
        }

        checkForDeath(player, enemy);
        checkForPermission();

        // enemy turn
        while(permission)
        {
            if(!enemy[1].turnTaken)
            {
                currentActor = 1;
            }
            if((!enemy[2].turnTaken) && (enemy[1].turnTaken))
            {
                System.out.println("entered player two");
                currentActor = 2;
            }
            if((!enemy[3].turnTaken) && (enemy[2].turnTaken) && (enemy[1].turnTaken))
            {   
                currentActor = 3;
            }
        }

        checkForDeath(player, enemy);
    }
}

public static void createActors()
{
    player[0] = new actor(1, "Knight");
    player[1] = new actor(1, "Mage");
    player[2] = new actor(1, "Rogue");

    enemy[0]  = new actor(1, "Slime");
    enemy[1]  = new actor(1, "Skeleton");
    enemy[2]  = new actor(1, "Necro");
}

public static void checkForPermission()
{
    if((player[1].turnTaken) && (player[2].turnTaken) && (player[3].turnTaken))
    {
        permission = true;
    }
}

public static void checkForDeath(actor[] player, actor[] enemy)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < player.length; i++)
    {
        if(player[i].HP <= 0)
            player[i].dead = true;
        if(player[i].dead == true)
            player[i].turnTaken = true;
        if(enemy[i].HP <= 0)
            enemy[i].dead = true;
        if(enemy[i].dead == true)
            enemy[i].turnTaken = true;
    }
}
```

}

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BattleUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
public static actor[] player = RPGv6.player;
public static actor[] enemy  = RPGv6.enemy;

public static int
actionType = 0,
actionName = 0,
target = 0;
static actor[] targetType;

static JButton
jbtAttack    = new JButton("Attack"), jbtSkills  = new JButton("Skills"),
jbtMagic     = new JButton("Magic"), jbtInventory = new JButton("Inventory"), 
jbtGo        = new JButton("Go!"),
kntSk1, kntSk2, kntSk3, mgSk1,
mgSk2, rgSk1, rgSk2, rgSk3, rgSk4, kntMgc1, kntMgc2,
mgMgc1, mgMgc2, mgMgc3, mgMgc4, rgMgc1, rgMgc2, rgMgc3,
invt1, invt2, invt3, invt4, invt5, invt6;
public static JButton
jbtply1 = new JButton(), jbtply2 = new JButton(), jbtply3 = new JButton(),
jbtnmy1 = new JButton(), jbtnmy2 = new JButton(), jbtnmy3 = new JButton();
public static JLabel 
ply1Name, ply1HP, ply1MP, ply1SP, ply1Status,
ply2Name, ply2HP, ply2MP, ply2SP, ply2Status,
ply3Name, ply3HP, ply3MP, ply3SP, ply3Status,
nmy1Name, nmy1HP, nmy1MP, nmy1SP, nmy1Status,
nmy2Name, nmy2HP, nmy2MP, nmy2SP, nmy2Status,
nmy3Name, nmy3HP, nmy3MP, nmy3SP, nmy3Status;
private static JPanel
pStatusField1, pStatusField2, pStatusField3,
eStatusField4, eStatusField5, eStatusField6;

public static JTextArea jta;
static Color defaultColor;

//CardLayout
private static CardLayout cardManager;
private static JPanel deck;
private static String names[] = { "KnightSkillsCard", "MageSkillsCard", "RogueSkillsCard",
                                  "KnightMagicCard", "MageMagicCard", "RogueMagicCard",
                                  "InventoryCard"};

public BattleUI(actor[] player, actor[] enemy)
{
    //begin pStatus
        // Labels displaying actor statuses
        ply1Name   = new JLabel(player[0].name);
        ply1HP     = new JLabel("HP: "+player[0].HP);
        ply1MP     = new JLabel("MP: "+player[0].MP);
        ply1SP     = new JLabel("SP: "+player[0].SP);
        ply1Status = new JLabel("OK"); // placeholder; will need to replace with a method to generate icons symbolizing status

        ply2Name   = new JLabel(player[1].name);
        ply2HP     = new JLabel("HP: "+player[1].HP);
        ply2MP     = new JLabel("MP: "+player[1].MP);
        ply2SP     = new JLabel("SP: "+player[1].SP);
        ply2Status = new JLabel("OK");

        ply3Name   = new JLabel(player[2].name);
        ply3HP     = new JLabel("HP: "+player[2].HP);
        ply3MP     = new JLabel("MP: "+player[2].MP);
        ply3SP     = new JLabel("SP: "+player[2].SP);
        ply3Status = new JLabel("OK");

        nmy1Name   = new JLabel(enemy[0].name);
        nmy1HP     = new JLabel("HP: "+enemy[0].HP);
        nmy1MP     = new JLabel("MP: "+enemy[0].MP);
        nmy1SP     = new JLabel("SP: "+enemy[0].SP);
        nmy1Status = new JLabel("OK");

        nmy2Name   = new JLabel(enemy[1].name);
        nmy2HP     = new JLabel("HP: "+enemy[1].HP);
        nmy2MP     = new JLabel("MP: "+enemy[1].MP);
        nmy2SP     = new JLabel("SP: "+enemy[1].SP);
        nmy2Status = new JLabel("OK");

        nmy3Name   = new JLabel(enemy[2].name);
        nmy3HP     = new JLabel("HP: "+enemy[2].HP);
        nmy3MP     = new JLabel("MP: "+enemy[2].MP);
        nmy3SP     = new JLabel("SP: "+enemy[2].SP);
        nmy3Status = new JLabel("OK");

        // Panels holding the statuses for each actor
        pStatusField1 = new JPanel();
            pStatusField1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
            pStatusField1.add(ply1Name);
            pStatusField1.add(ply1HP);
            pStatusField1.add(ply1MP);
            pStatusField1.add(ply1SP);
            pStatusField1.add(ply1Status);
        pStatusField2 = new JPanel();
            pStatusField2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
            pStatusField2.add(ply2Name);
            pStatusField2.add(ply2HP);
            pStatusField2.add(ply2MP);
            pStatusField2.add(ply2SP);
            pStatusField2.add(ply2Status);
        pStatusField3 = new JPanel();
            pStatusField3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
            pStatusField3.add(ply3Name);
            pStatusField3.add(ply3HP);
            pStatusField3.add(ply3MP);
            pStatusField3.add(ply3SP);
            pStatusField3.add(ply3Status);

        eStatusField4 = new JPanel();
            eStatusField4.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
            eStatusField4.add(nmy1Name);
            eStatusField4.add(nmy1HP);
            eStatusField4.add(nmy1MP);
            eStatusField4.add(nmy1SP);
            eStatusField4.add(nmy1Status);
        eStatusField5 = new JPanel();
            eStatusField5.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
            eStatusField5.add(nmy2Name);
            eStatusField5.add(nmy2HP);
            eStatusField5.add(nmy2MP);
            eStatusField5.add(nmy2SP);
            eStatusField5.add(nmy2Status);
        eStatusField6 = new JPanel();
            eStatusField6.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
            eStatusField6.add(nmy3Name);
            eStatusField6.add(nmy3HP);
            eStatusField6.add(nmy3MP);
            eStatusField6.add(nmy3SP);
            eStatusField6.add(nmy3Status);

        // Add the labels for actor status fields into buttons
        jbtply1.add(pStatusField1);
        jbtply2.add(pStatusField2);
        jbtply3.add(pStatusField3);

        jbtnmy1.add(eStatusField4);
        jbtnmy2.add(eStatusField5);
        jbtnmy3.add(eStatusField6);

        // Divides information display for player and enemy actors
        JPanel pStatusFieldPlayer    = new JPanel();
            pStatusFieldPlayer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            pStatusFieldPlayer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Player"));
            pStatusFieldPlayer.add(jbtply1);
            pStatusFieldPlayer.add(jbtply2);
            pStatusFieldPlayer.add(jbtply3);

        JPanel pStatusFieldEnemy     = new JPanel();
            pStatusFieldEnemy.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enemy"));
            pStatusFieldEnemy.add(jbtnmy1);
            pStatusFieldEnemy.add(jbtnmy2);
            pStatusFieldEnemy.add(jbtnmy3);

        // Panel for displaying actor information to user
        JPanel pStatus   = new JPanel();
            pStatus.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            pStatus.add(pStatusFieldPlayer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            pStatus.add(pStatusFieldEnemy, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //end pStatus

    // Panel for displaying action options
    JPanel pActions   = new JPanel();
        pActions.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        pActions.add(jbtAttack);
        pActions.add(jbtSkills);
        pActions.add(jbtMagic);
        pActions.add(jbtInventory);
        pActions.add(jbtGo);

    // Text Area for displaying a narration of the executed actions
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jta = new JTextArea(5, 22));
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener
        (new AdjustmentListener() 
            {   
                public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) 
                {   
                    e.getAdjustable().setValue(e.getAdjustable().getMaximum());   
                }
            }
        ); 
        jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jta.setLineWrap(true);
        jta.setSize(250, 90);
        jta.setEditable(false);

    // begin CardLayout
        // CardLayout Panel for displaying the abilities available to the current actor
        deck = new JPanel();
        cardManager = new CardLayout(); 
        deck.setLayout( cardManager );

        JPanel
        card1 = new JPanel(),
        card2 = new JPanel(), 
        card3 = new JPanel(),
        card4 = new JPanel(), 
        card5 = new JPanel(), 
        card6 = new JPanel(), 
        card7 = new JPanel(); 

            //card1
        kntSk1 = new JButton("Deadly Blow 20SP");
        kntSk2 = new JButton("Cripple 35SP");
        kntSk3 = new JButton("Maim 40SP");
            //card2
        mgSk1 = new JButton("Meditate");
        mgSk2 = new JButton("Balm 15SP");
            //card3
        rgSk1 = new JButton("Poison 35SP");
        rgSk2 = new JButton("Brew 20SP");
        rgSk3 = new JButton("Blind 30SP");
        rgSk4 = new JButton("Backstab 45SP");
            //card4
        kntMgc1 = new JButton("Ward 15MP");
        kntMgc2 = new JButton("Bless 20MP");
            //card5
        mgMgc1 = new JButton("Fireball 40MP");
        mgMgc2 = new JButton("Acid Burn 50MP");
        mgMgc3 = new JButton("Heal 25MP");
        mgMgc4 = new JButton("Time Stop 75MP");
            //card6
        rgMgc1 = new JButton("Dazzle 20MP");
        rgMgc2 = new JButton("Sting 30MP");
        rgMgc3 = new JButton("Heal 20MP");
            //card7
        invt1 = new JButton("Health Potion");
        invt2 = new JButton("Mana Potion");
        invt3 = new JButton("Stamina Potion");
        invt4 = new JButton("Shield Gem");
        invt5 = new JButton("Water of Life");
        invt6 = new JButton("Shuriken");

        card7.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        card1.add(kntSk1);
        card1.add(kntSk2);
        card1.add(kntSk3);

        card2.add(mgSk1);
        card2.add(mgSk2);

        card3.add(rgSk1);
        card3.add(rgSk2);
        card3.add(rgSk3);
        card3.add(rgSk4);

        card4.add(kntMgc1);
        card4.add(kntMgc2);

        card5.add(mgMgc1);
        card5.add(mgMgc2);
        card5.add(mgMgc3);
        card5.add(mgMgc4);

        card6.add(rgMgc1);
        card6.add(rgMgc2);
        card6.add(rgMgc3);

        card7.add(invt1);
        card7.add(invt2);
        card7.add(invt3);
        card7.add(invt4);
        card7.add(invt5);
        card7.add(invt6);

        deck.add(card1, names[0]);
        deck.add(card2, names[1]);
        deck.add(card3, names[2]);
        deck.add(card4, names[3]);
        deck.add(card5, names[4]);
        deck.add(card6, names[5]);
        deck.add(card7, names[6]);
    // end CardLayout

    // Add Listeners to the Buttons
        kntSk1.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        kntSk2.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        kntSk3.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        mgSk1.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        mgSk2.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        rgSk1.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        rgSk2.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        rgSk3.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        rgSk4.addActionListener(new SkillListener());
        kntMgc1.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        kntMgc2.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        mgMgc1.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        mgMgc2.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        mgMgc3.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        mgMgc4.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        rgMgc1.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        rgMgc2.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        rgMgc3.addActionListener(new MagicListener());
        invt1.addActionListener(new InventListener());
        invt2.addActionListener(new InventListener());
        invt3.addActionListener(new InventListener());
        invt4.addActionListener(new InventListener());
        invt5.addActionListener(new InventListener());
        invt6.addActionListener(new InventListener());


        jbtply1.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());
        jbtply2.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());
        jbtply3.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());

        jbtnmy1.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());
        jbtnmy2.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());
        jbtnmy3.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());

        jbtnmy1.addMouseListener(this);
        jbtnmy2.addMouseListener(this);
        jbtnmy3.addMouseListener(this);


        jbtAttack.addMouseListener(this);
        jbtSkills.addMouseListener(this);
        jbtMagic.addMouseListener(this);
        jbtInventory.addMouseListener(this);

        jbtAttack.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jbtSkills.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jbtMagic.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jbtInventory.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        jbtGo.addActionListener(new GoListener());

    // Add everything in
    JPanel pNarration = new JPanel();
        pNarration.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JPanel pHolder    = new JPanel();
        pHolder.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        pHolder.add(pActions, BorderLayout.WEST);
    JPanel pHolder2   = new JPanel();
        pHolder2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        pHolder2.add(pStatusFieldPlayer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pHolder2.add(pStatusFieldEnemy, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JPanel pHolder3   = new JPanel();
        pHolder3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, - 200, 0));
        pHolder3.add(deck);
        pHolder3.add(pNarration);

    // add contents into frame
    add(pHolder, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(pHolder2);
    add(pHolder3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Action Selection
        if(e.getSource() == jbtAttack)
        {
            actionType = 0;
            actionName = 0;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
            System.out.println("attack button pressed");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jbtSkills)
        {
            // Selecting these buttons determines what card and options are displayed to the user
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jbtMagic)
        {

        }
        if(e.getSource() == jbtInventory)
        {

        }
    }
}

class GoListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == jbtGo)
        {
            System.out.println(RPGv6.currentActor);
            System.out.println(actionName);
            System.out.println(actionType);
            System.out.println(target);
            if(RPGv6.actionDetermined && RPGv6.targetDetermined)
            {
                executeSkill(actionType, actionName, player[RPGv6.currentActor], targetType[target]);
                player[RPGv6.currentActor].turnTaken = true;
                System.out.println("Go button pressed");
            }
            else
            {
                jta.append("You need to select an action and a target!");
            }
        }
    }
}

class SkillListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Knight Skills
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {   //Deadly Blow
            actionType = 1; // 0 = Attack; 1 = Skill; 2 = Magic; 3 = Inventory
            actionName = 0; // Determines which skill to use
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 1;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 2;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }

        // Mage kills
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 0;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 1;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }

        // Rogue Skills
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 0;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 1;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 2;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 1;
            actionName = 3;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
    }
}

class MagicListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 0;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 1;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }

        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 0;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 1;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 2;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 3;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }

        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 0;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 1;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 2;
            actionName = 2;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
    }
}

class InventListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 3;
            actionName = 0;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 3;
            actionName = 1;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 3;
            actionName = 2;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 3;
            actionName = 3;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 3;
            actionName = 4;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == "")
        {
            actionType = 3;
            actionName = 5;
            RPGv6.actionDetermined = true;
        }
    }
}

class SelectionListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Player Targets
        if(e.getSource() == jbtply1)
        {
            targetType = player;
            target = 0;
            RPGv6.targetDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jbtply2)
        {
            targetType = player;
            target = 1;
            RPGv6.targetDetermined = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jbtply3)
        {
            targetType = player;
            target = 2;
            RPGv6.targetDetermined = true;
        }

        // Enemy Targets
        if(e.getSource() == jbtnmy1)
        {
            targetType = enemy;
            target = 0;
            RPGv6.targetDetermined = true;
            System.out.println("enemy0 selected");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jbtnmy2)
        {
            targetType = enemy;
            target = 1;
            RPGv6.targetDetermined = true;
            System.out.println("enemy1 selected");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jbtnmy3)
        {
            targetType = enemy;
            target = 2;
            RPGv6.targetDetermined = true;
            System.out.println("enemy2 selected");
        }
    }
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtAttack)
    //{
    //  //ui.deColorButtonBackGrounds();
    //  jbtAttack.setBackground(Color.orange);
    //}
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtSkills)
    //{
    //  //ui.deColorButtonBackGrounds();
    //  jbtSkills.setBackground(Color.orange);
    //}
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtMagic)
    //{
    //  //ui.deColorButtonBackGrounds();
    //  jbtMagic.setBackground(Color.orange);
    //}
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtInventory)
    //{
    //  ui.deColorButtonBackGrounds();
    //  jbtInventory.setBackground(Color.orange);
    //}
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
{
    //if(e.getSource() == )
    //{
    //  eStatusField4.setBackground(Color.red);
    //}
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtOpt2)
    //{
    //  eStatusField5.setBackground(Color.red);
    //}
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtOpt3)
    //{
    //  eStatusField6.setBackground(Color.red);
    //}
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
{
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtOpt1)
    //{
    //  eStatusField4.setBackground(defaultColor);
    //}
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtOpt2)
    //{
    //  eStatusField5.setBackground(defaultColor);  
    //}
    //if(e.getSource() == jbtOpt3)
    //{
    //  eStatusField6.setBackground(defaultColor);
    //}
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

public static void createAndShowGui(actor[] player, actor[] enemy)
{
    BattleUI frame = new BattleUI(player, enemy);
    frame.setTitle("Battle");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

public static void executeSkill(int actionType, int actionName, actor caller, actor target)
{
    if(actionType == 0)//Attack
    {
        actions.attack(caller, target);
    }
    if(actionType == 1)
    {

    }
    if(actionType == 2)
    {

    }
    if(actionType == 3)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tags are an opportunity to quickly identify technology/languages being used. You didn't mention *anywhere* what language you're working in, and you picked several irrelevant tags to boot. I've edited some slightly better ones in.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I think you need to break it into chunks and walk through it and look over your logic step by step.

I started reading through and immediately found some logic concerns. For example:

```
if((!player[2].turnTaken) && (player[2].turnTaken) && (player[1].turnTaken))
{   
    currentActor = 2;
}
```

take note of `(!player[2].turnTaken) && (player[2].turnTaken)` This state alone is not possible as it can not be both true and false. I have a feeling that there are likely many more places like this.
(Also, you don't need to wrap the `a == b` conditions in `()` unless you are trying to cluster groups of logic together.)

i.e. 
`if((a == true) && (b == true) && (c == true)) {}`

is the same as:

`if(a == true && b == true && c == true) {}`

and, even easier to read (personal opinion)

`if(a && b && c) {}`